# 8x8 matrix of buttons

Tags: gpio, connection

It is possible to connect 8x8 matrix of buttons to the Pi using 16 GPIO pins, 8 for rows and 8 for columns? What are possible alternatives of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known as multiplexing but you will get bonus points for mentioning [Charlieplexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing) where it all began.

[image]

So you save allot of GPIO's but you have to work out a software solution now. There are several ways to work out the pins but you can leverage the speed of the Pi to set the GPIO's in a specific way, thousands of times a second. The benefit of this circuit is that you do not need diodes to control voltage flow.

**Sequential exploration of rows:**

> In this method, the I/O pins connecting the rows are all configured as
>   output and those connecting the columns are defined as input, or
>   vice-versa. The column lines, which are inputs to the microcontroller,
>   are pulled-high using the internal pull-up resistors. Therefore, the
>   default input to these lines is 1. The state for the matrix keypad can
>   be explored by turning the rows low sequentially, one at a time, and
>   reading the columns. For example, set the first row to 0 and read all
>   the columns. If any key has been pressed in that row, the
>   corresponding column line must read as 0. Otherwise, go to the next
>   row and set it to 0, and read the columns again. This process is
>   repeated until a 0 is found in a column. This determines the row and
>   column for the pressed key, thus giving the exploration code for that
>   key.

**Simultaneous exploration of rows and columns:**

> In this method, all rows and columns are explored simultaneously in
>   two phases. First, the rows are configured as output and the columns
>   as input. Internal pull-ups are enabled on the column lines. Then all
>   rows are set to 0 and the columns are read. In any key has been
>   pressed, the corresponding column will be read as 0. This detects the
>   column but not its row. The whole process is reversed next. The rows
>   are configured as input and the columns as output. Internal weak
>   pull-ups are now enabled on row lines. All columns are set to 0, and
>   the rows are read. The row that reads 0 contains the pressed key. This
>   gives both the row and column for the pressed key. This approach of
>   exploring the keypad is relatively faster than sequential exploration
>   approach.

<sup>*[Methods source](http://embedded-lab.com/blog/?p=3428#sthash.Fes0z6Iq.dpuf)</sup>

---

Multiplexing can also be applied the other way, by turning on things at specific places in the matrix. A nice example are LED's cubes, where you can trigger LED's in a 3D matrix using the correct sequence of GPIO's.

[image]

Comment: So it uses 8 pins as output, for columns, and 8 pins as input, for rows. Output 1 is turned on, each row (input) checks if button is pressed in that column, then it moves to the next column and checks for each row again. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Sorry. I think that image I used wont work for any combination. That is a simpler version. You actually want to power all the switches using Vcc and 16 GPIO's to detect the ROW/COL. Updating now.

Comment: I updated the answer to use another software technique based on some info I found on another site. I was demonstrating a different technique. There are many ways to accomplish this but the updated answer uses least components and leveraged the speed of working with Pulse Width Modulation.

Comment: Ok, these methods are good. Now I need to figure out how to do the wiring to the pi. [link](http://oi58.tinypic.com/dq6alf.jpg)

Comment: The suggestions by @ppumkin will work, but the Pi has only 17 possible pins for I/O. You will need to disable the serial console. Also be aware the I2C pins have on-board 1.8k pull-up resistors.

Comment: He could use an IO expander too. I suspect it was more theoretical question than practical.

Comment: If you set one column to HIGH, you must set the other columns to inputs. Otherwise, if the user presses 2 button in the same row, you'll create a short between HIGH of the one column, and the LOW of the other column. Also note that pressing more than 2 buttons at once, can in some cases give false positives.