# Rpi GPIO Python Pad4Pi Module for Interrupt Based Matrix Keypad - Where is the Interrupt command?

Tags: raspbian

I'm using membrane keypad with raspberry pi, and with the help from pad4pi library.

I can't seem to find the interrupt command in pad4pi library.

What's the interrupt command for any of the keys, i.e. one of the key pressed interrupts the running program?

Answer (score -1):

***Question***

> How come there is no interrupt command in the Pad4pi keypad library?

---

***Answer***

> Well, you don't need to write pin interrupt functions yourself.
>
> The python module will setup interrupt pins during start up and
> interchanging row and columns as interrupt/input and output rows and
> columns.  Everything is done in the background.
>
> You might like to read my answer for more details of the keypad scanning algorithm to the question in [Ref 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98440/multiple-gpio-buttons).
>
> Note the "***Is interrupt flag set condition***" in Step 2 of the keypad scanning flowchart.

---

***References***

(1) [Pad4pi - An interrupt based Python library for reading matrix keypad Raspberry Pi GPIO pins.](https://pypi.org/project/pad4pi/)

(2) [AdaFruit Membrane 3x4 Matrix Keypad - $4](https://www.adafruit.com/product/419)

(3) [Multiple GPIO Buttons](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98440/multiple-gpio-buttons)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - [MicroChip Keypad Scanning Algorithm - MicroChip](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98440/multiple-gpio-buttons)*

[image: keypad scan method]

*.END*