# Detecting connections between non-GPIO and GPIO pins in Pico?

Tags: gpio, pi-pico

### XY-problem

I have a keyboard that consists of two halves. Each half uses 16 pins. The pins in each half are aligned in a 8x8 matrix yielding 64 key presses that can be detected, and two times 64=128 keys in total. I can set a value on GPIO pin 8, and then read out the value on GPIO pin 9 to determine whether the key on the intersection of 8 and 9 is pressed. The values are identical if there is a connection between GPIO pin 8 and 9. A keypress realises such a connection.

### Example Code

After using the following script to detect a connection between two GPIO pins (GPIO pin 8 and GPIO pin 9) on a Raspberry Pico:

```
from machine import Pin
import time

led = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
output_line= Pin(8, Pin.OUT)
input_line = Pin(9, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)


while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    if(input_line.value()):
        led.toggle()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("connected")
    output_line.value(1)
    print("set high")
```

### Issue

The pico however does not have 2 times 16 GPIO pins but 26 (25 excluding the led I think). Which means it does not have enough pins for two 8x8 matrices (which require two times 8+8=32 pins). So I am looking for another 7 pins that I can set values to, or read values/connections from on other pins, to get 32 pins on which the two keyboard matrices connections/keypresses can be detected.

### Solution Attempts: Software

So I tried setting the value of pin 25 and reading out the value of pin 26, however, that disconnects the Pico when I try to find that connection, for example when I connect `GPIO27_A1` to `AGND`.

### Solution Attempt: Software Example

An example I had in mind was: I assume the 3V3 sets some value/voltage, e.g. 3 Volts. I assumed that if I connect the `3V3` pin to a GPIO pin `10`, and read out the value of `10`, it would be `False` if it is not connected to `3V3`, and `True` if it is connected to `3V3`. If those assumptions are valid, that would grant me another row/pin from which I can read off key presses.

### Solution Strategy: Hardware

So I could either buy cables that allow me to connect two jumper cables to a single pin, and then send those pulses/values to the left and right half of the keyboard, (multiplying the signals of the first 8 GPIO pins by two), and using another 16 pins to read out the values.

However, I was having some difficulty in finding single female to
double female jumper cables, and thought it would be more elegant to not buy extra material if I can squeeze the functionality out of the board itself.

### Question

Hence, I would like to ask: Is it possible to also determine connections*/(logic levels) between non-GPIO pins (and GPIO pins) in some way?

*This assumes that I am aware that there is just a single wire going from one pin to another, meaning, if the values/voltages on two pins is identical (and manually set on 1 of the two), I assume there is a connection.

Comment: I think you have a got a bit lost explaining your method for solving some problem.  What is the problem?  What are you trying to actually achieve?

Comment: Thank you, I included the XY problem at the top to provide the context.

Comment: You have asked variants of this question before. You have already been told it is NOT POSSIBLE to detect connections between pins. GPIO can **detect logic levels** (a few Pico pins can detect analog, but this is a red herring). Again you have been told key scanning is a common technique - you should find hundreds of examples. Basically you scan 8 pins in turn and detect on another 8. No one is going to write your code for you. The Pico has 26 × multi-function GPIO pins - more than enough.

Comment: Thank you for indicating I did not convey my question clearly. Though similar, this question is different from the others. 1st I asked [how to detect connections between GPIO pins](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/132372/detecting-connection-between-two-arbitrary-gpio-pins-on-pico), then I asked [if its safe to connect arbtrary pins in arbitrary setups](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135525/safely-using-gpio-pins-of-raspberry-pico). This question is on whether non-GPIO pins can also be used to detect connections. It is not asking for code, it asks for insight.

Comment: Ah, the way to go is using a 'matrix': https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104066/rpi-gpio-python-pad4pi-module-for-interrupt-based-matrix-keypad-where-is-the-i

Comment: What is the end application, it appears to be a continuity or cable tester. If speed is not critical there are many I2C parts that will give you 8 or 16 iopins (PCF857 (4) (5), you can put at least 8 on an I2C bus which only requires two wires from your computer. Looking at this as an X-Y problem, none of the Xs will connect with another X and same for Ys. If so you can parallel the Xs or Ys and save 8 pins. More information always helps to get a better answer as does a schematic and links to technical information on hardware parts.

Answer (score 0):

While ever you continue to think about connections rather than INPUTS, OUTPUTS & logic levels you are going to have difficulty.
Magic thinking e.g. non-GPIO pins (whatever they may be) won't help.
Connections are a derived concept from data.

You need to stop thinking like a marketer and start thinking like an engineer.

It now appears that you have an (unreferenced) keyboard with 2 8*8 matrices.

To an engineer this suggests you need 8 OUTPUTS & 16 INPUTS.

If I were doing this in MicroPython I would create 16 Pin.irq handlers for the inputs and poll each of the 8 outputs with a suitable delay.